# Pull one record out ordered by a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple sql query that goes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE UserId = '$sessfacebook'"
```

This selects me a username, a facebookid and a numeric score. I need to pull this record out but I need to find out which position the record is in if the table were ordered by the score. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another query for that

```
SELECT count(*) Position
FROM leaderboard
WHERE score >= (
    SELECT score
    FROM leaderboard
    WHERE UserId = '$sessfacebook')
```

Which you can slot in as a subquery

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM leaderboard b
    WHERE b.score >= leaderboard.score) Position
FROM leaderboard
WHERE UserId = '$sessfacebook'
```

Comment: aha ok, so how do I get the position out of that query...how do I assign that to a variable? Sorry my sql isn't brilliant.

Comment: @eld - in both queries, the column is named "Position". So in php, you would reference `$pos = intval($result['position']);`

Comment: That's brilliant. I actually needed to do <= rather than >= to get what I want but it's working. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to select the number of records with a higher score:

```
SELECT  * 
,       (select count(*) from leaderboard lb2 where lb2.score > lb1.score) as Rank
FROM    leaderboard lb1
WHERE   UserId = '$sessfacebook'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from (SELECT @ranknum := @ranknum + 1 AS rank, 
leaderboard.* FROM leaderboard , (SELECT @ranknum := 0) r order by score desc) 
as sortedboard where USERID = '$sessfacebook' limit 1;
```

This will create a table alias as leaderboard with rank, and get the required record from it.
Will work for you, tested it.